# Visualforce CommandButton's deadlock situation?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have a list of contacts displayed using [Salesforce Wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). Now I am trying to implement a custom button, clicking on it will give an alert message.

VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Try Me" action="{!selectedContacts}" 
             onclick="if{!selectedConsList.size < 1}{alert('Please select at least one Contact');}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Controller:

```
...
public List<Contact> selectedConsList {get; set;}
...
public PageReference selectedContacts(){
    List<Contact> selectedCons = new List<Contact>();

    for(contactWrapper cont: getMyConts()){
        if(cont.selected == true ){
            selectedCons.add(cont.wrapCon);
        }
    }
    selectedConsList = selectedCons;

    System.debug('selectedConsList Size: ' +selectedConsList.size()); 
    System.debug('selectedConsList: ' +selectedConsList);

    contactList=null; //Emptying the Selected list.
    return null;
}
```

When I click on the button, it just renders the page and no alert is being displayed. Is this even valid logic to have the Contacts list variable(selectedConsList) in the action method that is being used for onclick event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a number of issues with your code. The initial issue is that you're not using a merge field syntax; it should be `{!selectedConsList.size < 1}`. However, this still won't work because onclick is called *before* your Apex Code is. Instead, you'd want to query your checkboxes directly in JavaScript, and prevent the code execution if you show the alert:

```
onclick="if(!document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { alert('Please select at least one record.'); return false;}"
```

You may need to change the querySelectorAll criteria if you have different types of checkboxes on your page, but this should get you started.

---

Working demo:

```
public class q212161 {
    public Integer[] items { get; set; }
    public q212161() {
        items = new Integer[] { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q212161">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!items}" var="item">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column>
                    {!item}
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="if(!document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { alert('Please select at least one row'); return false; }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

Final answer based on commentary:

```
onclick="if(!document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=selectedCon]:checked').length) { alert('Please select at least one row!'); return false; }"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74835/discussion-on-answer-by-sfdcfox-visualforce-commandbuttons-deadlock-situation).